# can i display something under a specific widget in the widgets menu

Tags: wordpress, widget

There is a plugin called 'widget context' that displays html code underneath widgets when they are expanded in the widget admin menu.

I would like to do the same thing but only display under specific widgets.

Answer (score 0):

**It's not** an easy task.

The answer I'd give here is [exactly the same](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/72939/12615)<sup>*</sup> I gave for a similar Q in WordPress StackExchange.

> *I know that the plugin Widget Logic does exactly that.*
>   *Dissecting its code, the excerpt bellow will output a textarea in all widgets.*

<sup>*</sup> displaying the box on selected widgets would make the task even harder...